# Смена цвета иконки и текста в BottomNavigationView при смене темы Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottom-navigation-view, android-selector

Есть чек бокс для переключения темы Андроид, пытаюсь менять цвет иконки и текста в BottomNavigationView, при смене чекбокса и темы соответственно. Есть один selector такого вида

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/control_active_tabbar" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/control_inactive_tabbar" />
</selector>
```

у самих цветов описанных в селекторе, есть описания для темной и светлой темы, но это все почему-то срабатывает через раз.
Причем по логам, тема действительно меняется, а вот цвета для иконки и текста, приходят либо с текущей темы, и изредка с той на которую переключаешься.
Может кто-нибудь с подобным сталкивался?

Comment: не разбивайте цвета в ресурсах на светлые и тёмные (-night), делайте это с темами приложения и используйте атрибуты из темы (например ?attr/myColor)

Comment: @IR42 Вам не сложно будет написать пример, как это может выглядеть, я не очень понимаю.

Answer (score 0):

Помог вот этот ответ, через AppCompatResources.getColorStateList - все значения color приходят корректно:

> If your min SDK is 23 you don't need the compat API for obtaining colors.
> If you don't use theme attribute references in colors and don't plan change, use Context.getResources().getColor(int) or getColorStateList(int) as you're used to. It's marked deprecated but functionally it's OK.
> If you want to use theme attribute references in colors on API 23+ only, use ContextCompat.getColorStateList(Context, int).
> If you use AppCompat and want to be able to use theme attribute references on all versions of Android, use AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(Context, int).

Взят от сюда: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47962074/whats-the-use-of-theme-in-context-getcolor)